# How to print with this technique?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I am using NASM 8086, I know another method of printing and that works fine. I am trying to do it in this way, it assembles but doesn't shows any output where is the mistake?

```
org 100h
segment data

section .text
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
mov [es:0],word 0x0741

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set an appropriate [video mode](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) first. For example:

```
mov ax,0x0001   ; SET VIDEO MODE 1 (40x25 16-color)
int 10h
```

Comment: Default video mode (3) should be okay. Try waiting for a key before exiting - your 'A' may be scrolling offscreen?

Comment: both works correct, mov ax,0x0001 and MOV AX,03H. The difference is that the first one prints bigger alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't see the result, because the screen scrolls up, but you try to print in the position 0,0; Try to type `cls` and then the name of the program. This way, the command prompt will not scroll the screen.